# Database is not created when i run my wcf project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, wcf, dbcontext

**user service**

I am new to code first EF, and WCF, i have created a test project which contains a Webforms project, a business logic (code first classes), a wcf project for my services and a data access later

this is the start up file of my wcf.

```
    public User Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            throw new Exception("User name or password cannot be empty");
        }

        var userContext = new UserContext();
        var user = userContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) &&
                                                         u.Password.Equals(password, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
        return user;
    }
```

**user context**

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    static UserContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new UserContextInitializer());
    }
}
```

I'm i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
using(var userContext = new UserContext())
{
   code(...)
}
```

You have forgotten a public constructor.

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public static UserContext() : base("name of database connection string")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new UserContextInitializer());
    }
}
```

Comment: that does not solve the issue, i don't have a connection string, shouldn't entity framework use my local database by default if that is not provided

Comment: @ifelabolz do you have SQL Express installed? EF will choose this if both are installed.

Comment: @user2697817 i have SQL server 2008 installed

Comment: Do you have LocalDb installed? EF picks this or SQL Express. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592674

Comment: If you have an SQL Server 2008 installed, you must provide an connection string or else EF will use SQL Express which is shipped with your Visual Studio. That is my guess, if you have SQL Manager you can connect to your local MSSQL express database. Mine is located under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA